# Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = null; При попытке создать пользователя в БД Firebase

Tags: unity3d, firebase

Вот мой код:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Firebase.Auth;

public class Firebase_connect_authorization : MonoBehaviour
{
    Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth;
    auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.LogError("User creation was canceled.");
                return;
            }
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogError("User creation encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                return;
            }
            if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                Debug.Log("User creation successfully completed");
                return;
            }

        });
    }
}
```

> Traceback:
>   NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object

Я понимаю, что ошибка в том, что объект `auth` пустой. Но почему он пустой не ясно. Я на форуме видел похожую проблема, но там проблема связана с auth.CurrentUser(); Но тут очевидно другая ошибка.

Comment: Проследите отладчиком за значением auth

Comment: я уже разобрался, оказывается нужно было в явно указать. ```Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = new Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefualtInstance;```

Answer (score 0):

нужно было в явно указать. Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = new Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefualtInstance;